# How to suppress output for skipped tests in Jasmine

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

If I have the scenario with 1000+ tests and want to run only selected portion of them I can use `fdescribe`.

The rest of tests are skipped which is great however they still pollute the console output. **How can I suppress the console output for skipped tests?**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're running tests via Karma, there is a spec reporter plugin that you can configure to ignore various things.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-spec-reporter

https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-spec-reporter-2

Add the following to your karma.conf.js:

```js
...
  config.set({
    ...
      reporters: ["spec"],
      specReporter: {
        suppressSkipped: true, // do not print information about skipped tests 
      },
      plugins: ["karma-spec-reporter"],
    ...
```

If you're not using Karma, then you need to find the proper Jasmine reporter and configure it, or create your own reporter.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine2-reporter

Comment: I am using Karma and I am not using spec reporter. What then?

Answer (score 22):

If you're using the mocha reporter:

```
reporters: ['mocha'],

mochaReporter: {
  ignoreSkipped: true,
},
```