# jest tests report - don't report skipped tests

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Is there a possibility to not report skipped tests during jest run? I use config:

```
"test": "jest src/tests",
"smoketest": "jest -t \"^(?=.*@HappyPath).*\" src/tests/",
```

but during the `npm run smoketest` it keeps reporting all tests that don't pass the regex check as skipped tests. In karma there is an option to do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33922521 but what about `jest`? I was trying to use `jest-runner-groups` tool, but it supports tagging tests on the file level and not on the test level (in other words: all tests in the single file have to belong to the same group).